# How to limit the number of characters per line without affecting a word?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

What I'm trying to do is open up a text file with some paragraphs and give each line a maximum width of X number of characters. However, I'm having a flaw in my algorithm as this will cut out words and it's not going to work. I'm not really sure how to go about this. Also I'm not sure how to make it change line.

I checked textwrap and I don't really want to use it at this point since I want to improve my algorithmic skills.

So my algorithm is to open the file:

```
f.open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

Now I have a list of all the lines. This is where I get stuck. How will I limit the length of each line when I print?

I'm really not sure how to go about this and would really appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: you should take a look at: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/textwrap.html

Comment: Since you're asking about algorithms rather than code or languages: basically, you want to look at the character that is start + n, and if it is whitespace, wrap there; if it is not whitespace, look at start + n - 1; if that is not whitespace, look at start + n - 2... There will be ways of optimizing this in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use standard [`textwrap` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html):

```
import textwrap
txt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
print '\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(txt, 20, break_long_words=False))
```

First, for reading files you should use `with` construction:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

def wrap(line):
    broken = textwrap.wrap(line, 20, break_long_words=False)
    return '\n'.join(broken)

wrapped = [wrap(line) for line in lines]
```

But you stated, that you don't want to use built-in textwrap, but do it on your own, so here is no-import solution:

```
import textwrap

lorem = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus ac commodo libero, at dictum leo. Nunc convallis est id purus porta,  
malesuada erat volutpat. Cras commodo odio nulla. Nam vehicula risus id lacus 
vestibulum. Maecenas aliquet iaculis dignissim. Phasellus aliquam facilisis  
pellentesque ultricies. Vestibulum dapibus quam leo, sed massa ornare eget. 
Praesent euismod ac nulla in lobortis. 
Sed sodales tellus non semper feugiat."""

def wrapped_lines(line, width=80):
    whitespace = set(" \n\t\r")
    length = len(line)
    start = 0

    while start < (length - width):
        # we take next 'width' of characters:
        chunk = line[start:start+width+1]
        # if there is a newline in it, let's return first part
        if '\n' in chunk:
            end = start + chunk.find('\n')
            yield line[start:end]
            start = end+1 # we set new start on place where we are now
            continue

        # if no newline in chunk, let's find the first whitespace from the end
        for i, ch in enumerate(reversed(chunk)):
            if ch in whitespace:
                end = (start+width-i)
                yield line[start:end]
                start = end + 1
                break
            else: # just for readability
                continue 
    yield line[start:]

for line in wrapped_lines(lorem, 30):
    print line
```

*EDIT* I didn't like version above, it is bit ugly and non-pythonic for my taste. Here's another:

```
def wrapped_lines(line, width=80):
    whitespace = set(" \n\t\r")
    length = len(line)
    start = 0

    while start < (length - width):
        end = start + width + 1
        chunk = line[start:end]
        try:
            end = start + chunk.index('\n')
        except ValueError: # no newline in chunk
            # we iterate characters from the end:
            for i, ch in enumerate(reversed(chunk)):
                if ch in whitespace:
                    end -= i # we have our end on first whitespace
                    break
        yield line[start:end]
        start = end + 1
    yield line[start:]
```

Comment: Note: the OP specifically stated he was aware of the `textwrap` option and did not want to use it (I understand that using `textwrap` is the best option but the OP wishes to learn).

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, @Ffisegydd, I totally missed it. I'll write another answer.

Comment: "from the scratch" solution added

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this. One approach is to look for the last space before the right margin and split the string there, printing the first part and repeat the searching and splitting on the second part.

Here's another approach: Split the text up into words and add the words to a line buffer one by one. If the next word would overflow the line, the line is printed first and it is reset. (As an extra, this code allows you to specify a left margin.)

```
def par(s, wrap = 72, margin = 0):
    """Print a word-wrapped paragraph with given width and left margin"""

    left = margin * " "
    line = ""

    for w in s.split():
        if len(line) + len(w) >= wrap:
            print left + line
            line = ""

        if line: line += " "
        line += w

    print left + line
    print



par("""What I'm trying to do is open up a text file with some
    paragraphs and give each line a maximum width of X number  of
    characters.""", 36)

par("""However, I'm having a flaw in my algorithm as this
    will cut out words and it's not going to work. I'm not really
    sure how to go about this. Also I'm not sure how to make it
    change line.""", 36, 44)

par("""I checked textwrap and I don't really want to use it at
    this point since I want to improve my algorithmic skills.""",
        64, 8)
```

Instead of printing, you could, of course, return a multi-line string with newlines or, probably better, a list of lines.

Comment: @Davidmh: Maybe, but the OP is "really not sure how to go about this", so it's more about the idea than about the implementation. The approach I've shown is a bit different from the other solutions here, because the text can be printed in successive, independent calls, so it needs a state. A global may not be the most Pythonic solution, but it works and I was a bit loth to create a class for a few lines that outline an idea.

Comment: precisely for that reason, the OP is a novice and should not be given bad advise. It can be easily reimplemented without classes or globals.

Answer (score 0):

Test.txt contains:

```
"""
What I'm trying to do is open up a text file with some paragraphs and give each line a    maximum width of X number of characters.
However, I'm having a flaw in my algorithm as this will cut out words and it's not going to work.
I'm not really sure how to go about this. Also I'm not sure how to make it change line.
"""
with open("test.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    max_width = 25 
    result = ""
    col = 0
    for line in lines:
        for word in line.split():
            end_col = col + len(word)
            if col != 0:
                end_col += 1
            if end_col > max_width: 
                result += '\n'
                col = 0    
            if col != 0:
                result += ' ' 
                col += 1
            result += word 
            col += len(word)
        print result


What I'm trying to do is
open up a text file with
some paragraphs and give
each line a maximum width
of X number of
characters.
What I'm trying to do is
open up a text file with
some paragraphs and give
each line a maximum width
of X number of
characters. However, I'm
having a flaw in my
algorithm as this will
cut out words and it's
not going to work.
What I'm trying to do is
open up a text file with
some paragraphs and give
each line a maximum width
of X number of
characters. However, I'm
having a flaw in my
algorithm as this will
cut out words and it's
not going to work. I'm
not really sure how to go
about this. Also I'm not
sure how to make it
change line.
```

Answer (score 0):

A part of a programmer's skills should be the ability to read and understand the source code written by someone else. I understand you do not want to use `textwrap` module. However, you can learn from its source code. The reason is that you have to *reverse engineer* also the parts that reflect a mental image of the problem from someone's else head. This way you can also learn how to write the things better.

You can find the `textwrap` implementation in `c:\Python34\Lib\textwrap.py`. You can copy and rename it to your working directory for experiments.

Answer (score -2):

To get the right approach you need to start by determining what you want to do with anything that is longer than the defined length.  Assuming you want a fairly traditional wrap where extra words flow to the next line you should have logic something like (note - this is pseudo code)

```
for(int lineCount=0; lineCount<totalLines; lineCount++){
    currentLine=lines[lineCount];
    if(currentLine.length < targetLength){
       int snipStart=currentLine.find_whitespace_before_targetLength;
       snip = currentLine.snip(snipStart, currentLine.length);
       if(lineCount<totalLines-1){
         lines[lineCount+1].prepend(snip);
       }else{
         //Add snip to line array, since the last line is too long
       }
    }
}
```